# Routes not starting in Karaf 4.1.1 but runs in ServiceMix

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf

I am using a simple camel-spring project which has a file route to copy from one location to another. But when i deploy the bundle and even the bundle is in Active State, not sure why the routes are not starting. Below are the dependent bundles i have started.

```
28 │ Active │  80 │ 4.1.1          │ Apache Karaf :: OSGi Services :: Event
53 │ Active │  80 │ 2.19.1         │ camel-commands-core
54 │ Active │  50 │ 2.19.1         │ camel-core
55 │ Active │  80 │ 2.19.1         │ camel-karaf-commands
59 │ Active │  50 │ 2.19.1         │ camel-spring
68 │ Active │  80 │ 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT │ A Camel Spring Route
```

But when i use the same Camel Spring Route bundle to install in Apache Service Mix , I see in the route-list that my routes are started and working fine. Do i need to have any other bundles to be start for my route bundle to work .

Please follow the link to take a look into the bundle.
[Link to Download Bundle](http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Spring-routes-are-not-starting-in-Karaf-4-1-1-td4051005.html)

Here is the Image of the simple project
[image]

Below the details from service mix which works.

```
karaf@root>list | grep Active
 43 | Active   |  50 | 2.16.5                             | camel-core
 47 | Active   |  50 | 2.16.5                             | camel-spring
 49 | Active   |  80 | 2.16.5                             | camel-karaf-commands
224 | Active   |  80 | 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT                     | A Camel Spring Route
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the `camel-spring-dm` feature in Karaf 4.1.1, eg `feature:install camel-spring-dm`. Also mind spring-dm is deprecated / dead so its not recommended to be used. Use OSGi Blueprint instead if you want to do XML routes in Karaf/ServiceMix with Camel.

Comment: Looks like the camel-spring-dm support is not present in 2.19.1. I did use blueprint and it works good in karaf 4.1.1 . But how do i use Spring @Components with Blueprint xml to refer the spring beans ? . Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You cannot use Spring `@Component` with Blueprint, its not Spring.

Answer (score 0):

In karaf 4.1.1 spring dm is not present by default. You need to first do

```
feature:repo-add spring-legacy 4.1.1
```

Comment: Thanks Christian. Getting problems in using. I am moving to apache service mix which already has the support to spring dm.

Comment: Do ot invest too much into getting spring-dm working. It is a dead project since a long time. Like Claus suggested it is better to move to blueprint.